# Difference between static and dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there any difference between static and dynamic projects in eclipse 3.x.when it will be use static project?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In static web project, you will not have Java, servlets and JSP etc. (server side scripts).
You can only have HTML, JavaScript etc.

Please check the link below, it will help you:

http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/what-is-the-difference-between-static-and-dynamic-websites/

Comment: The OP mentioned static and dynamic projects (not web projects specifically) but I'll also make that assumption. In addition to the link above, also see: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fccwebprj.html . It's Juno, but the description seemed useful. I haven't tried the feature, but it also mentions how static sites can be converted to dynamic sites

Answer (score 8):

**Static Web Project** is written entirely using HTML. Each web page is a separate document and there are no databases or external files that are drawn upon. means that you can edit any web page using FrontPage Editor, Dreamweaver or pay your web developer to make updates for you.

**Dynamic Web Project** are builds upon more complex code like PHP, ASP, JSP, Servlet java file etc. in this project server side coding.
You should select *Dynamic web project* to get more benifits.

Answer (score 5):

Dynamic and static. Dynamic web projects can contain dynamic Java EE resources such as servlets, JSP files, filters, and associated metadata, in addition to static resources such as images and HTML files. Static web projects only contains static resources. When you create Web projects, you can include cascading style sheets and JSP tag libraries (for dynamic Web projects), so that you can begin development with a richer set of project resources.

For more :
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fccwebprj.html